# Using Sequelize Js and the ANY parameter for a array column

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In PostgreSQL, I can get the result I want with the following command.

```
select * from applications where 1 = ANY(channels)
```

But I could not find how to do it with sequelize js. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the raw query is the simplest solution.